# JOIN inside while loop mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables:

Table **`transactions`**

[image]

Table **`addonlist`**

[image]

Table **`addons`**

[image]

I want to `echo` all items on `addons` and see if `addon_id` from table `addons` matched the `laddon_id` from table `addonlist` with the given `transac_id` to add a **note** to the item traced.

I have this code and I can make a **note** to the items that found in `addonlist` but it `echoes` the same item from `addons`.

```
    $getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addons LIMIT 10");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){
        $addonid = $rows['addon_id'];
        $addondesc = $rows['description'];
        $addonprice = $rows['price'];
        $addonstat = $rows['status'];
        $checkaddon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions t, addonlist al WHERE t.transac_id='44005' and t.transac_id=al.transac_id");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkaddon)){
            $caddonid = $rows['laddon_id'];
            if(mysql_num_rows($checkaddon) and $addonid == $caddonid){
                echo "$addondesc already in your list"; // NOTE: item is already in your list
            }
        }
        echo "<strong>$addondesc </strong><button>Add to list</button>";
    }
```

**This would be displaying(my expectation):**

```
Coke 1 Litre - already in your list
Tuna Sandwich - already in your list
Hotdog Sanwich - add button
Chicken Sandwich - add button
Ham & Egg Sandwich - add button
Ham & Cheese Sandwich - add button
Grilled Cheese Burger - add button
Clubhouse Sandwich - add button
Goto - add button
Arrozcaldo - add button
```

**But what it displays:**

```
Coke 1 Litre - already in your list
Coke 1 Litre - add button `// This wouldn't be appearing`
Tuna Sandwich - already in your list
Tuna Sandwich - add button `// This wouldn't be appearing`
Hotdog Sanwich - add button
Chicken Sandwich - add button
Ham & Egg Sandwich - add button
Ham & Cheese Sandwich - add button
Grilled Cheese Burger - add button
Clubhouse Sandwich - add button
Goto - add button
Arrozcaldo - add button
```

**EDIT:**

Please let me know if my `database structure` is bad or if it is just my `codes`.

Comment: Why don't you use a `LEFT JOIN` to get everything in one query?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`? hmmmm, not so familiar, but I gotta try. I will take your suggestion. Thanks. I guess I have to do more study about it.

Comment: You don't need `mysql_num_rows($checkaddon)` in the `if`. If it returned `0` rows, you wouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: Why are you getting all the rows from `addon_list` in the first place? Why don't you just query for `WHERE laddon_id = $addonid`? Then you can just check `if (mysql_num_rows($checkaddon))`

Comment: That's basically what the `LEFT JOIN` does.

Comment: I tried this and I got items from `addons` matching the `id` in `addonlist` and with matched `transac_id`.

`$matchaddon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addons a, addonlist al, transactions t WHERE t.transac_id='44005' and al.transac_id=t.transac_id and a.addon_id=al.laddon_id");`

But editing the line `a.addon_id=al.laddon_id` to `a.addon_id!=al.laddon_id` makes every items doubled except for the items found on `addonlist`. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: That's an inner join. It will only return rows that match in all 3 tables. You need to use a left outer join, so it will return rows from the first table even if they don't have a match in the second table.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to get everything in one query. For addons that aren't in `addonlist` you'll get `NULL` for the columns from `addonlist`, and you can test that in the loop.

```
$getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT a.addon_id, a.description, a.price, a.status, l.laddon_id
                          FROM addons AS a
                          LEFT JOIN addonlist AS l ON a.addon_id = l.laddon_id AND l.transac_id = '44005'
                          LIMIT 10");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)) {
    $addonid = $rows['addon_id'];
    $addondesc = $rows['description'];
    $addonprice = $rows['price'];
    $addonstat = $rows['status'];
    if ($rows['laddon_id']) {
        echo "$addondesc already in your list";
    } else {
        echo "<strong>$addondesc </strong><button>Add to list</button>";
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a need to join with `transactions`, as you're not using anything from that table.

Comment: Oh. I have no idea of what I'm using. I didn't know that I'm using `INNER JOIN`. Thanks for the info. And for clarifying me to the difference of `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addons LIMIT 10");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){
    $addonid = $rows['addon_id'];
    $addondesc = $rows['description'];
    $addonprice = $rows['price'];
    $addonstat = $rows['status'];
    $checkaddon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions t, addonlist al WHERE t.transac_id='44005' and t.transac_id=al.transac_id");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkaddon)){
        $caddonid = $rows['laddon_id'];
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkaddon) and $addonid == $caddonid){
            echo "$addondesc already in your list"; // NOTE: item is already in your list
        }else{
            echo "<strong>$addondesc </strong><button>Add to list</button>";
        }
    }
}
```

Your issue is that your loop has the "Add to list" line added to every iteration, instead of only the iterations without an $addondesc already in the list.

Comment: That's my old code and it was more worst. It doubles `all` the items.

Comment: You also have the "$checkaddon = mysql_query" line containing a fixed transaction id.  If you have updated code, post it as an update to your question.  But you'd be better off with a join as Barmar stated.

Comment: I used it just for example. Yeah. I guess I have to go to `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your code. Even though the addon item is in your list it is printed again after the inner while loop completes.

```
$getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addons LIMIT 10");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){
    $addonid = $rows['addon_id'];
    $addondesc = $rows['description'];
    $addonprice = $rows['price'];
    $addonstat = $rows['status'];
    $checkaddon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions t, addonlist al WHERE t.transac_id='44005' and t.transac_id=al.transac_id");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkaddon)){
        $caddonid = $rows['laddon_id'];
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkaddon) and $addonid == $caddonid){
            echo "$addondesc already in your list"; // NOTE: item is already in your list
        }else{
            echo "<strong>$addondesc </strong><button>Add to list</button>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy and paste my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
$getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addons a LEFT JOIN addonlist al ON a.addon_id = al.laddon_id WHERE a.status = 1");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){
            if($rows['transac_id'] == "" || $rows['transac_id'] == NULL)
                $output = "<strong>{$rows['description']}</strong><button> - Add to list</button>";
            else
                $output = "<strong>{$rows['description']}</strong><button> - already in your list</button>";
            echo $output."<br/>";
        }
```